# Django not able to submit form using ModelForm

Tags: django, django-forms

The form is always sending a Get request instead of a Post which has been explicitly added using method = "POST". So, not able to persist the data to db. I have just started with Django so, any help will be appreciated.
Below are the code snippets:

**create_order.html**

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'home' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{form}}
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

***urls.py***

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.dashboard, name='home'),
    path('products/', views.product, name='products'),
    path('customer/<str:cust_id>/', views.customer, name='customer'),
    path('create_order/', views.create_order, name='create_order'),
]
```

**views.py**

```
def create_order(request):
    
    form = OrderForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("In Post", request.method)
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')
    else:
        print("In else", request.method)
        print(form.is_valid())
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/')    
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/create_order.html', context)
```

**terminal output**

`In else GET False`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are making a POST request to the wrong view. It should be the `create_order` view, so:

```
<form method="POST" action="{% url 'create_order' %}">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form }}
    <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>
```

Note that you should not validate the form in case of a GET request, since then you only render the form. So the view logic should be:

```
def create_order(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        print("In Post", request.method)
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('home')
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
    context = {'form' : form}
    return render(request, 'accounts/create_order.html', context)
```

Comment: Thanks @Willem, this worked out. Also, I could do this without even adding the action.`<form method="POST" action="">
 {% csrf_token %}
 {{form}}
 <input class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="Submit">
</form>`

Answer (score 0):

Try to add form action method in your HTML file

```
 <form action="" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
            {{ form}}
            <input type="submit" value="Submit Feedback" />
        </form>
    </div>
```